# Variance of expectation vs. Expectation of variance

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-distribution

Can we compare
$Var_X[E_Y(f(X,Y))]$
and
$E_Y[Var_X((f(X,Y))]$ where $f()$ is any function of $X$ and $Y$ iid? I suspect $Var_X[E_Y(f(X,Y))]$ is the smaller one. Though I couldn't find a single counter example, is there any formal proof to show (or counter example to count) this?

Comment: From the terminology you used, I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for. However, this [Q & A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959113/what-is-the-difference-between-expectation-variance-for-statistics-versus-p) might be the answer. If not, perhaps you could clarify your question?

Comment: @Kat Hi, I want to compare two things in the population level: 1) the variance (w.r.t $X$) of the conditional expectation of $f(X,Y)$ (w.r.t $Y$ given $X$); and 2) the expectation (w.r.t $Y$) of  the conditional variance of $f(X,Y)$ (w.r.t. $X$ given $Y$). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 7):

The [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) is $$\mathrm{Var}_{(X,Y)}[f(X,Y)]=\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]+\mathbb E_X[\mathrm{Var}_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]\\=\mathrm{Var}_Y[\mathbb E_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]+\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]\tag{0}$$

In the specific setting when
$$\mathbb E_{X|Y}[f(X,Y)|Y)]=0\qquad\text{a.s.}\tag{1}$$
we thus get
$$\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]+\mathbb E_X[\mathrm{Var}_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]=\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]$$
which implies
$$\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]\le\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]\tag{2}$$

Take $f(x,y)=a(x)b(y)$ and $X,Y$ independent. Then
$$\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]=\textrm{Var}_X(a(X))\mathbb E_{Y}[b(Y)]^2\tag{3}$$and
$$\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]=\mathbb E_Y[b(Y)^2]\mathrm{Var}_{X}(a(X))\tag{4}$$
implying that (3) is always smaller than (4).

The inequality
$$\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]\le\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]\tag{5}$$also holds when $f(x,y)=a(x)+b(y)+c$.

A last indication is that, when assuming wlog that $\mathbb E_{(X,Y)}[f(X,Y)]=0$, (5) is equivalent to
$$\mathbb E_{(X,Y)}[f(X,Y)^2]\ge \mathbb E_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}^2]+\mathbb E_Y[\mathbb E_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}^2]\tag{6}$$

Running a small Monte Carlo experiment with some highly varying and assymetric functions $f$ and a Student's $\mathfrak t_4$ on $X$ and $Y$ did not exhibit cases when (6) does not hold:

```
N=1e4;m=mean
fxy=outer(rt(N,4),rt(N,4),f)
fxy=fxy-m(fxy) #centred
m(fxy^2)-m(apply(fxy,1,m)^2)-m(apply(fxy,2,m)^2))
```

Comment: I added a couple `]` to balance out eqns, looks like a copy paste propagation

Comment: Thanks. I see that $\mathbb E_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}=0$ almost surely is a sufficient condition for $\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]\le\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]$. But do you think the opposite inequality is possible, i.e. $\mathrm{Var}_X[\mathbb E_{Y|X}\{f(X,Y)|X\}]\ge\mathbb E_Y[\mathrm{Var}_{X|Y}\{f(X,Y)|Y\}]$?

Comment: Let $f(X,Y)=X,$ so that its expectation conditional on $X$ is $X,$ whence the left hand side of the hypothesized inequality is the variance of $X.$ On the right hand side the conditional variance also is the variance of $X$ (because $Y$ is assumed independent of $X$), whence its expectation is still the variance of $X.$  Thus, equality holds, showing "the opposite inequality is possible."

Comment: @whuber Ah that's true. But still hard to think of an example of the opposite "strict" inequality.

Comment: What a great work and simulations! Decomposing $f(x,y)$ into $a(x)$ and $b(y)$ is exactly the same thing as I have tried before. It seems the inequality holds for many general $f(x,y)$ empirically, hard to prove though.